# How to prevent deleteting specific user?

Tags: users

I've create user called 'root' and I want to prevent to be deleted. How can I do that in back-end, without any plugin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Prevent deleting user accounts in WordPress Back-end?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215714/how-to-prevent-deleting-user-accounts-in-wordpress-back-end)

Comment: Without any plugin? You mean programmatically? With a custom plugin?